# Convert grammar into an LL(1) grammar which recognises the same language

Tags: compiler, grammar, ambiguity

I have the following sample question for a compilers exam and wanted to check my solution.

```
Convert the following grammar into an LL(1) grammar which recognises the same 
language:

E -> E + T  
E -> T  
T -> id 
T -> id() 
T -> id(L) 
L -> E;L 
L -> E
```

For my answer I have

```
E  -> T E'  
E' -> + T | ε  
T  -> id 
T  -> id() 
T  -> id(L) 
L  -> E L' 
L' -> ;E | ε
```

Can anybody verify the answer?

**Edit**

Ok so would it be similar to...

```
E  -> T E'  
E' -> + E | ε  
T  -> id 
T  -> id() 
T  -> id(L) 
L  -> E L' 
L' -> ;E | ε
```

Comment: cstheory is for *research-level* questions. cs.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

> E -> E + T | T
>   T -> id | id() | id(L)
>   L -> E;L | E

E -> TE'
E'-> +TE' | ε

> L -> E;L | E

L -> EL'
L'-> ;L | ε

you need to transform T as I did with L otherwise it will be an LL(3)

Comment: No, L is not correct.  In the original grammar, L will recognize a list containing one or more expressions.  As he has the LL(1) version written, L will recognize a list containing exactly one or two expressions.

Comment: you're right. I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Close, but not quite.

Consider the sentence "a + b + c", where a, b, and c are all ids.

The original grammar recognizes this, courtesy of the E + T recursion.

Your grammar recognizes "a + b", then crashes, because you do not recur.

[added later] Now, consider "a(b;c;d;e)".  Your grammar crashes after "a(b;c", for a similar reason.

Comment: Oh right.. any idea how to fix it? The exam is in the morning xD